# For each customer show: Company name, contact name, number of calls where the number of calls is fewer than 5

Tags: mysql, sql

the data Description is in the sqlzoo.net/wiki/Help_Desk. Expected result is displayed below the question, if you enter the link(sqlzoo.net/wiki/Helpdesk_Medium_Questions No.8 question). If you want to find the actual result, you can copy my code in the textarea below the No.8 question and run it(sqlzoo.net/wiki/Helpdesk_Medium_Questions No.8 question). I did not put the actual answer here, because it is too long to display.

For this practice,No 8 For each customer show: Company name, contact name, number of calls where the number of calls is fewer than 5.
I use

```
select Company_name,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    count(Issue.Caller_id) as nc
from Issue
left join Caller on Caller.Caller_id = Issue.Caller_id
left join Customer on Caller.Company_ref = Customer.Company_ref
group by Company_name,
    first_name,
    last_name
having count(Issue.Caller_id) < 5
order by nc desc
```

However I do not think this match the expected result because of too many rows. Could you tell me what wrong with my code?

Comment: You can't tell what's wrong? How can we? Share sample data, expected results, actual results

Comment: Sorry, the data Description is in the http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Help_Desk. Expected result is displayed below the question, if you enter the link(http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Helpdesk_Medium_Questions   No.8 question).
If you want to find the actual result, you can copy my code in the textarea below the No.8 question and run it(http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Helpdesk_Medium_Questions  No.8 question).
I did not put the actual answer here, because it is too long to display. Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More clean and readable solution

```
select cu.company_name,ca2.first_name,ca2.last_name,count(*) as nc
from Customer cu
inner join Caller ca on ca.company_ref = cu.company_ref 
inner join Issue i on i.caller_id = ca.caller_id
inner join Caller ca2 on ca2.caller_id = cu.contact_id
group by cu.company_name,ca2.first_name,ca2.last_name
having nc < 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Company_name,
first_name,
last_name,
count(Issue.Caller_id) as nc
FROM Issue WHERE count(Issue.Caller_id) < 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I just leave this correct answer for people who practice sql in the sqlzoo.

```
select a.Company_name as Company_name,First_name as first_name, Last_name as last_name,nc from 
(select Company_name,
    contact_id,
    count(Issue.Caller_id) as nc
from Issue
 join Caller on Caller.Caller_id = Issue.Caller_id
 join Customer on Caller.Company_ref = Customer.Company_ref
group by Company_name,Contact_id
having count(Issue.Caller_id) < 5
order by nc desc) a
join 
(select * from Caller) b
on a.contact_id = b.Caller_id
```